# Is there a relationship between norms/transfers in equivariant homotopy theory and norms in the Tate construction / ambidexterity?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

In homotopy theory, the word "norm" is commonly used in two different ways (well, surely there are other ways, but these two have a particular familial resemblence).

1. Let $G$ be a finite group. A $G$-spectrum $E$ can be restricted to an $H$-spectrum for any subgroup $H \subseteq G$, and there is an "inclusion of fixed points" map $E^G \to E^H$. If $E$ is "genuine" then there is also a "wrong-way" map in the other direction, called the *transfer*. There is a similar multiplicative story: if $E$ is a $G$-ring spectrum, then for any map of finite $G$-sets $T \to S$, there is an "inclusion of fixed points" map $(\wedge^S E)^G \to (\wedge^T E)^G$. If the multiplicative structure on $E$ is "genuine" then there is also a "wrong-way" map in the other direction, called the *norm*.
2. Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a spectrum $E$. Then there is a natural composite map $E^{hG} \to E \to E_{hG}$, but there is also a "wrong-way" map in the other direction, called the *norm*. If the norm is invertible, the action is *ambidextrous*, and the obstruction to ambidexterity (i.e. the cofiber $E^{tG}$ of the norm) is the *Tate construction*.

**Question:** Is there a relationship between these two uses of the word "norm" (or perhaps between "norm" in the second sense and "transfer")?

I think this is more than a coincidence of terminology partly because Nikolaus and Scholze use norm data in the second sense to describe cyclotomic spectra, a sort of equivariant spectrum, which data is normally encoded in terms of transfers. But I haven't studied Nikolaus-Scholze closely enough to extract what's going on.

Comment: The transfer that appears for a genuine G-spectrum is a refinement of the Borel trace/norm in the sense that there is a factorization $E_{hG} \to E^G \to E^{hG}$. In the multiplicative case you also have something similar, but not every Borel G-spectrum comes with a multiplicative norm for free (unlike the additive one), and you'd want to replace the homotopy orbits by a multiplicative variant which I dunno a good name for in the non-fully-commutative case. (In the G-E_infty case, you'd like to take homotopy orbits in the category of E_infty rings, for example)

Comment: @DylanWilson Thanks! From what you said, I don't quite understand how the genuine equivariant transfer relates to the factorization $E_{hG} \to E^G \to E^{hG}$?

Comment: Take H to be trivial in your (1), but now note that the genuine restriction and transfer maps are equivariant for the trivial action on the fixed points, so they factor as indicated.

Comment: @DylanWilson I'm still not seeing it. Let $e$ be the trivial group. In (1), I have transfer and restriction maps between $E = E^e$ and $E^G$. When I take homotopy orbits I get maps between $E_{hG}$ and $E^G\wedge BG_+$, and when I take homotopy fixed points I get maps between $E^{hG}$ and $Fun(BG_+,E^G)$. So I think I'm missing something...

Comment: To produce a map from $X$ to a homotopy limit like $E^{hG}$ I need to produce a natural transformation from the constant diagram on $X$ to the BG-indexed diagram E, and I have such a thing as part of the data of a genuine G-spectrum, where X is $E^G$. If it's easier, you can work internally to the world of genuine G-spectra: there's a map $EG_+ \to S^0$ of $G$-spectra which induces natural transformations $EG_+ \wedge E \to E$ and $E \to F(EG_+, S^0)$. Now take genuine G-fixed points of both sides. You must show that the genuine fixed points of the source of the first map and target of

Comment: the second map are indeed the homotopy fixed points and homotopy orbits, which can be done in various ways.

Comment: @DylanWilson Thanks for sticking with me, I think I understand the construction now: Taking orbits of the transfer map $E \to E^G$, we obtain $E_{hG} \to E^G \wedge BG_+$. The map $BG^+ \to S^0$ then gives us $E^G \wedge BG_+ \to E^G$. Composing, we get $E_{hG} \to E^G$. Then we compose this with the inclusion of fixed points $E^G \to E^{hG}$ to get a map $E_{hG} \to E^{hG}$. Fantastic! Now why does this composite map agree with the norm map in the sense of (2)? (By the way, an explanation or a reference for this fact would make a great answer to the original question!)

Comment: By the way, in your last comment it sounds like you're saying that $(EG_+ \wedge E)^G = E_{hG}$ and $Fun(EG_+,E)^G = E^{hG}$ but only the second actually holds, right? It seems to me that $(EG_+ \wedge E)^G = 0$, it's $(EG_+ \wedge E)_G = E_{hG}$... Also I think I'm dimly remembering being told this before -- there's some range of groups / families where the data of a genuine $G$-spectrum is _equivalent_ to supplying some factorizations of the Tate norms for each subgroup in the family, right?

Comment: @TimCampion No, $(EG_+\wedge E)^G=E_{hG}$ (it's a version of the Adams isomorphism). For your second question, you can find the most general version of that statement in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01976)

Comment: @DenisNardin Thanks! I'm confused, though. If $E$ is just a pointed $G$-space, then $EG_+  \wedge E = (EG \times E) / (EG \times\{\ast\})$, and since $EG$ has a free $G$-action, $EG \times E$ has a free $G$-action. So I really don't see any fixed points other than the basepoint, unless things work very differently stably...

Comment: @TimCampion Contrary to the case of pointed $G$-spaces, the smash product in G-spectra is not computed fixed point-wise (i.e. $(E\wedge F)^G\neq E^G\wedge F^G$), so your proof doesn't work in that case If you want to discuss more these things may I suggest we move to chat? This comment chain is getting unwieldy.

Comment: For the record, we did move the discussion to chat. [Link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80614/discussion-related-to-https-mathoverflow-net-questions-306654). Anybody should feel free to join the discussion there. I get the feeling that neither Dylan nor Denis is likely to write up an answer -- if nobody does, I'll probably try to write a CW response summarizing what I've learned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a bit more of an organized answer:

First you have to decide how you'd like to model the notion of a genuine $G$-spectrum. There are at least ways that it's currently in vogue to do this, each of which is convenient for different purposes. (My groups are finite below, and I won't write down functors that aren't homotopically meaningful- so everything is 'derived'.)

1. One could begin with the homotopy theory of $G$-spaces, where weak equivalences are detected by checking on all fixed points and then 'invert' $\Omega^{\rho}$ or $\Sigma^{\rho}$, where $\rho$ is the regular representation. There are lots of ways of doing this, but no matter how you do it you will be able to present any $G$-spectrum as a homotopy colimit $X = \mathrm{hocolim}\, S^{-n\rho}\wedge\Sigma^{\infty}X_{n\rho}$ where the $X_{n\rho}$ are pointed $G$-spaces. This way of thinking about things makes it easy to define symmetric monoidal, accessible functors $\mathrm{Sp}^G \to \mathcal{C}$ since they'll be determined by what they do to suspension spectra. For example, from this point of view you can define *geometric* fixed points by doing what you expect: commuting with the formation of suspension spectra, commuting with homotopy colimits, and being symmetric monoidal. The other type of fixed points, *genuine* fixed points, are essentially uniquely determined by the property that the functor $(-)^G: \mathrm{Sp}^G \to \mathrm{Sp}$ is exact and satisfies $\Omega^{\infty}(X^G) = (\Omega^{\infty}X)^G$. (This functor is not symmetric monoidal- for example, it doesn't even send the unit to the right place, by the tom Dieck splitting). Alternatively, one can use that every stable homotopy theory is canonically enriched in spectra, and take the spectrum of maps from $S^0$ to $X$. Now, in this setting I sketched an answer to your question about transfers (the classical answer) which came from the map $\mathrm{E}G_+ \to S^0$. This induces a map $(\mathrm{EG}_+ \wedge X)^G \to X^G$. Now, why is it the case that $(\mathrm{EG}_+ \wedge X)^G$ is the same as the homotopy orbits? (A case of the 'Adams isomorphism'). You can prove this inductively using the standard bar filtration of $\mathrm{EG}_+$, i.e. inductively define a map $(\mathrm{sk}_j\mathrm{E}G_+ \wedge X)_{hG} \to (\mathrm{sk}_j\mathrm{E}G_+ \wedge X)^G$ and show it's an equivalence. The base case and inductive case reduce to the statement that there's a natural equivalence $(T_+ \wedge X)_{hG} \to (T_+ \wedge X)^G$ where $T$ is a finite free $G$-set. In other words, $(T/G)_+ \wedge X = \mathrm{map}_{\mathrm{Sp}}((T/G)_+, X)$ (using the self-duality of finite sets in $\mathrm{Sp}$) is naturally equivalent to $\mathrm{map}_{\mathrm{Sp}^G}(S^0, T_+ \wedge X)$. This, finally, follows because every finite $G$-set is self dual in $\mathrm{Sp}^G$: embed into some $G$-representation and produce a collapse map as in the proof of Atiyah duality to define the duality datum.
2. Another choice is to *define* the homotopy theory of genuine G-spectra as 'spectral Mackey functors', following Guillou-May and Barwick-Dotto-Glasman-Nardin-Shah, just take the homotopy theory of product preserving functors $\mathrm{Span}(G) \to \mathrm{Sp}$ where the former denotes the $(2,1)$-category of finite $G$-sets with mapping groupoids given by the groupoid of spans. And here I'm working $\infty$-categorically, so these are homotopy coherent functors. The value of the functor on the orbit [G/H] is the H-fixed points. In particular, there are natural inclusions of both the orbit category and its opposite into the category of spans. The map $[G] \to [*]$ and its 'opposite' automatically, by functoriality, gives the maps $X_{hG} \to X^G$ and $X^G \to X^{hG}$. The identification of the composite as the usual norm is then a kind of `double-coset formula', i.e. it follows from the formula for composition of spans coming from pullbacks.
3. Finally, there is the paper of Glasman which codifies and makes precise ideas of Greenlees and Greenlees-May: G-spectra can be described by their collection of *geometric* fixed points, and gluing data having something to do with Tate spectra. From this point of view it's easiest to say what the transfer maps here are in the case of something like $G=C_p$ (so I don't have to talk about generalized Tate constructions and so on). From this point of view, a $C_p$-spectrum is a triple $(X, X^{\Phi C_p}, X^{\Phi C_p} \to X^{tC_p})$ where $X$ is a Borel $C_p$-spectrum. The genuine fixed points are then *defined* as the pullback of $X^{hC_p} \to X^{tC_p} \leftarrow X^{\Phi C_p}$. This automatically produces a map $X_{hC_p} \to X^{C_p}$ factoring the 'norm/trace' since the Tate spectrum is the cofiber of the norm/trace.

All of the above is well-documented, with references enough to suit any taste. There's Lewis-May-Steinberger, the 'Alaska notes', an online book of Schwede, the first few sections of Hill-Hopkins-Ravenel and their appendices, that paper of Glasman's, etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks, Dylan! From your answer, I get the impression that the compatibility of the transfer with the Tate map is so basic to equivariant homotopy theory that really it's one of the criteria that any foundations for equivariant homotopy theory needs to satisfy. And thus its proof is something that's highly dependent on which foundations one works in. That is very enlightening, thanks!